# Declare beans for all profiles except one, using Spring profiles (XML)

Tags: java, spring

I'd like to know, using Spring XML profiles, if it is possible to declare Spring beans for all profiles, except the dev profile.

My usecase is that I would like to declare my JDBC datasource as being JNDI provided for profile "dev", while it is created for other profiles.

I'd like to have something like:

```
<beans profile="dev" >
    ... DataSource JNDI ...
</beans>
<beans profile="!dev" >
    ... DataSource creation ...
</beans>
```

Is there a solution? Or the only way is to do:

```
<beans profile="dev" >
    ... DataSource JNDI ...
</beans>
<beans profile="integration,valid,preprod,prod" >
    ... DataSource creation ...
</beans>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simpler way would be like this:

General datasource creation for any profile:

```
<bean name="datasource" ...>
```

then specific for dev:

```
<beans profile="dev" >
   <bean name="datasource" ...>
</beans>
```

Comment: Do these go in the same file?

Answer (score 2):

You can use **!**, for spring version higher than Spring 3.2 M1.

So this way is ok:

```
<beans profile="!dev" >
    ... DataSource creation ...
</beans>
```